# The email was sent only to a few (170)targeted audience despite of selecting the data extension which has 3800 records

Tags: marketing-cloud

We sent out an email today using guided send and for that I selected a data extension which has 3800 records. but, the email was sent only to 170 subscribers. Is there any specific reason why this might happen? Any possible insights or thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you verified that there are A.) Active subscribers, B.) Not duplicates, and C.) Valid Email Addresses? That is a huge difference, either way I would definitely put in a ticket to global support about it and see what they can find.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Lukas' answer: The marketing cloud operates a background check of email addresses against a variety of criteria that isn't transparent to users. As we ran into something like this with a customer we had a support engagement to check the reasons.

Some of the factors I know of:

- known spam trap address
- collection address like info@, admin@,...
- confirmed global marketing cloud unsubscribe (across all customers)

They do this because those tend to be typical signs of purchased lists with uncertain permission status.

I suggest you identify the non sent to addresses to get an insight if you have collection accounts as an issue and open a support ticket to let them enable those. However, they will ask for a reason to do so. In the mentioned case it was a business model addressing small businesses that often use those as their only email address.

If this isn't the issue and in general you should check the origin of the addresses affected before you open the ticket or try another send because technically you are violating terms of service when you send to addresses with unknown permission status and potentially harm not only your sender reputation but also the reputation of the sending service.

Hope that helps you in proceeding with the issue.

Comment: Exactly, Stephan. It is called the List Detective and is described here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221426&type=1

Answer (score 0):

You should check the status of your subscribers in All Subscribers list. They could potentially be set to Held or Unsubscribed, preventing the emails from being sent out to them. However this percentage seems to be very high.

Another point, which is worth checking, is your Data Extension. If you create a sendable Data Extension, but don't store the Email Address in a field with Email Address as type, the email will only be sent out to recipients who already exist in All Subscribers. This is due to the Subscriber Key mapping the record in your DE to the subscriber in All Subs, and takes the email from there. New subscribers can't be added, as Email Address is missing from sendable DE.